# Add views to a TableLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, view, tablelayout

**What do I want to achieve?**

My goal is to create a sudoku field programmatically, so I  want to add 9x9 EditText-views to my existing TableLayout.

**What is my problem?**

Easy said: The EditText-views are not showing up.

**What have I tried?**

Well.. my google attempts could be recognized as a DDOS-Attack.. ;)
But seriously, I googled a lot, read some documentations etc. but could not find appropriate information solving my problem.

**My Sudoku activiy code:**

```
    public class Sudoku : Activity
{
    private EditText[,] tbs;
    private TableLayout grid;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        //set view
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Sudoku);

        //initializations
        tbs = new EditText[9,9];
        grid = FindViewById<TableLayout> (Resource.Id.grid);

        //preparation
        prepareControls ();
    }

    private void prepareControls()
    {
        int size = Conversion.PixelsToDp(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels, Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density) / 15;
        int x_default = 10;
        int x = x_default;
        int y = x_default;
        int margin = 4;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (size, size);

        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {
            TableRow trow = new TableRow (this);
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
                //lparams.LeftMargin = x;
                //lparams.TopMargin = y;
                EditText tb = new EditText (this);
                tb.SetHeight (size);
                tb.SetWidth (size);
                tb.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
                tb.SetTextColor (Color.Argb (1, 75, 75, 75));
                tb.SetBackgroundColor (Color.White);
                tb.LayoutParameters = lparams;
                tbs[col, row] = tb;
                //layout.AddView (tb, lparams);
                trow.AddView (tb);
                x += size;

                if ((col + 1) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    x += margin;
                }

                if ((col + 1) % 9 == 0)
                {
                    y += size;
                    x = x_default;
                }
            }

            if ((row + 1) % 3 == 0)
            {
                y += margin;
            }

            grid.AddView (trow);
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional information**

Environment: Xamarin

Language: C#

API Level: API 15

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why don't you create your layout using XML?

Comment: @joao2fast4u - Because it would be pretty annonying to add 81 text views by xml